# C++ Matrix multiplication type detection

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

In my C++ code I have a Matrix class, and some operators written to multiply them. My class is templated which mean I can have int, float, double ... matrices.

My operator overload is classic I guess

```
    template <typename T, typename U>
    Matrix<T>& operator*(const Matrix<T>& a, const Matrix<U>& b)
    {
    assert(a.rows() == b.cols() && "You have to multiply a MxN matrix with a NxP one to get a MxP matrix\n");
    Matrix<T> *c = new Matrix<T>(a.rows(), b.cols());
    for (int ci=0 ; ci<c->rows() ; ++ci)
    {
      for (int cj=0 ; cj<c->cols() ; ++cj)
      {
        c->at(ci,cj)=0;
        for (int k=0 ; k<a.cols() ; ++k)
        {
          c->at(ci,cj) += (T)(a.at(ci,k)*b.at(k,cj));
        }
      }
    }
    return *c;
  }
```

In this code I return a matrix of the same type than the first parameter i.e. `Matrix<int> * Matrix<float> = Matrix<int>`. My question is how can I detect the most precised type among the two I give to not lose too much precision i.e. to have `Matrix<int> * Matrix<float> = Matrix<float>` ? Is there a clever to do it ?

Comment: you could supply conversions (eg. `Matrix<int>` to `Matrix<float>`) and allow only the same type for the other operations

Comment: are you sure creating the object on **heap** is what you what?

Comment: I want to use a lot of reference to avoid memory copies. Is there another way to do it ?

Comment: A `float` is not more precise than an `int` (well, a 32 bit int).  A `float` cannot distinguish between max int and max int-1, for example.  `new` is bad in your code.  Returning a reference is bad in your code.  The `at` method is poor, unless it is a checked variant of `()`: using `operator()` or two calls to `operator[]` is more idiomatic.  In my experience, fixed-dimensional matrices are often more useful than variable-dimensional matrices, and allow for static size type checking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is just the type that happens when you multiply a `T` by a `U`. That can be given by:

```
template <class T, class U>
using product_type = decltype(std::declval<T>() * std::declval<U>());
```

You can just use that as an extra defaulted template parameter:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename R = product_type<T, U>>
Matrix<R> operator*(const Matrix<T>& a, const Matrix<U>& b) {
    ...
}
```

---

In C++03 you can accomplish the same thing by doing a giant series of overloads with lots of small helper types like so (this is how Boost does it):

```
template <int I> struct arith;
template <int I, typename T> struct arith_helper {
    typedef T type;
    typedef char (&result_type)[I];
};

template <> struct arith<1> : arith_helper<1, bool> { };
template <> struct arith<2> : arith_helper<2, bool> { };
template <> struct arith<3> : arith_helper<3, signed char> { };
template <> struct arith<4> : arith_helper<4, short> { };
// ... lots more
```

We then can write:

```
template <class T, class U>
class common_type {
private:
    static arith<1>::result_type select(arith<1>::type );
    static arith<2>::result_type select(arith<2>::type );
    static arith<3>::result_type select(arith<3>::type );
    // ...

    static bool cond();
public:
    typedef typename arith<sizeof(select(cond() ? T() : U() ))>::type type;
};
```

Assuming you write out all the integer types, then you can use `typename common_type<T, U>::type` where before I used `product_type`.

If this isn't a demonstration of how cool C++11 is, I don't know what is.

---

Note, `operator*` **should not** return a reference. What you're doing will leak memory.

Comment: Ok I will try it. But I don't get the difference between an operator and a function that returns a reference. Is it a bad programming practice to build variable inside a function and returns a reference to it ?

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but couldn't we just use `auto funcName(blahBlah) -> decltype(T * U)` here?

Comment: BTW, there is no C++11 tag on this question.  decltype/auto may not exist for the OP.  An answer using type traits might be appropriate.

Comment: @davidbak sure, but I could equally argue that in the absence of a tag, we should assume the latest standard. Those who can't use it for good reasons can specify otherwise up-front, whereas in other cases, everyone can benefit from the many improvements in C++11 and beyond.

Comment: @baptiste - w.r.t. your question about returning references, you need to study that, for example, [here at GotW](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/002.htm) and other places.  w.r.t. the difference between an operator and a function: there is no difference, except for the syntax of calling it.

Comment: @baptiste If returning something created within the function, you must return by value or smart pointer - not by a reference or a bare pointer to a local variable. Anything else will return an invalid reference or leak memory respectively. This is fundamental.

Comment: @underscore_d - I'm not downvoting or denigrating your answer in any way ... but _someone_ might want to provide a non C++11 solution ...

Comment: ah if it uses C++11 it may be problematic as I would like to avoid it. What is the corresponding method using type_traits ? sorry for the tag !

Comment: @davidbak I don't have an answer, so it doesn't put me up nor down. That hypothetical someone is welcome to provide another method. Whoever said they couldn't? What exactly is the point of this detour?

Comment: @underscore_d `decltype(T * U)` isn't a valid expression if `T` and `U` are types. You need objects to multiply together. That's what `declval` gives you.

Comment: Barry: Thanks! @baptiste Perhaps you can add a tag to your question specifying the latest C++ version you can easily use; it might help to bring in answers (assuming we have such a tag...!)

Comment: I use GCC 4.8.4 so I guess it's C++03 even if with some extensions I could use C++11. But I don't want to.

Comment: @baptiste I added the C++03 mess of how to do this. Also, gcc 4.8.4 supports C++11 and you should use it.

Comment: @Barry Thanks !! I will have to check this reference problem then as well !!

Comment: Somewhat related, the imminent GCC v6 is taking a gigantic leap from C++98 to C++14 _as its default_ (albeit plus the `gnu++14` additions). **Finally!** Anyway, +1 for explaining how tortuous this is in C++03 vs how huge of an upgrade C++11 was ;-)