# Struggling to select a type using a templated structure

Tags: c++, templates, nested, c++03

I have a structure that I declare like this:

```
template <typename T, typename U> struct select_type;
```

I specialize it with:

```
template <> struct select_type<float, double>
{
  typedef double type;
};
```

And so on for several types like `<double, float>`, `<int, float>`...

I use it in some of my templated functions like:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename select<T,U>::type R >
smu::Matrix<R> operator*(const smu::Matrix<T>& a, const smu::Matrix<U>& b)
{
/* code here */
}
```

I tried several way to use it, without the `R`, without `typename` but most of the time I have an error asking for a `nested-name parameter before select`. The truth is I never done that and I don't know how I should use the structure. Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here. The way you're declaring `R`:

```
typename select<T,U>::type R
```

is as a *value* of type `select<T,U>::type`. That's not what you want - you want `R` to be that *type*. And secondly, `R` is a non-deduced context - it's a template parameter that isn't specified in any of the arguments so it cannot be deduced, it can only be explicitly specified. But you can't really explicitly specify it either since that defeats the point of having convenient `operator*` anyway.

In C++11 and later, you would make it a *defaulted* type parameter:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename R = typename select<T,U>::type>
smu::Matrix<R> operator*(const smu::Matrix<T>& a, const smu::Matrix<U>& b)
```

But in C++03, you can't have default function template parameters, so you just have to write it out:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
smu::Matrix<typename select<T,U>::type> operator*(const smu::Matrix<T>& a,
    const smu::Matrix<U>& b)
{
    typedef typename select<T,U>::type R;

    /* rest as before */
}
```

Comment: I asked the same question last week and you were the one to answer with the promotion type solution adapted from C++11: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773931/c-matrix-multiplication-type-detection This way looked much better but I had some issues implementing it as C++03 doesn't allow function call in templates... So I decided to do it another way. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename T, typename U>
smu::Matrix<typename select<T, U>::type> operator*(
    const smu::Matrix<T>& a, const smu::Matrix<U>& b)
```